# RSelenium or Javascript: Expand all java expandable element on a website

Tags: java, r, rvest, rselenium

I am working on a project right now that requires me to scrape information from this website:

- https://www.domstol.no/enkelt-domstol/hoyesterett/saksliste/berammingsliste/

I have already managed to scrape the table with RSelenium and Rvest. But there are some details I would like to add to the dataframe, which can be found in an expandable java (?) object. I have illustrated the object here:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF7eq.png)

Essentially, I need to expand ALL of them before scraping in order to include them. Is there an easy way to do this with a code? Yesterday I had a script that clicked them all manually, which took hours to complete.

Is it possible to inject a code on the website that expands them all, or have RSelenium execute a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script will allow you to scrape the web page and select the relevant dates and the court. Modify "Query" with the date range and the court you need.  I picked the first court in the list.  You can find the court codes by inspecting the page and searching for FormData.Court.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(httr)
    library(rvest)
    
    #################################
    ## FUNCTION TO PROCESS DATA    ##
    #################################
    
    parseDetails <- function(pg_dtls){
      
      dt <- pg_dtls %>%
        html_elements('dt') %>%
        html_text()
      
      dd <- pg_dtls %>%
        html_elements('dd') %>%
        html_text()
      
      tbl <- pg_dtls %>%
        html_element('table') %>%
        html_table()
      
      df <- as.data.frame(dd, row.names = dt) %>% set_names("Details")
      
      rtnList <- list(mainData = df, otherData = tbl)
    }
    
    ###############################
    ##  SCRAPE WEB PAGE          ##
    ###############################
    
    url <- "https://www.domstol.no/enkelt-domstol/hoyesterett/saksliste/berammingsliste/"
    
    query <- list('FormData.From'="25.02.2022",
                  'FormData.To'="07.03.2022",                  
'FormData.Court'="AAAA2104220835148622091WAFLAU#EJBOrgUnit")
    response <- POST(url, body = query)
    dtls <- content(response, "parsed") %>%
      html_elements("button") %>% 
      html_attr("data-action") %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      paste0("https://www.domstol.no/", .) %>%
      map(read_html)
    
    
    scrapedData <- map(dtls, parseDetails)
```